# Vmware - gcc version (null) was not found

Tags: vmware, gcc, virtualhost, vmware-workstation, tools

I couldn't install my VMware on Ubuntu. Whenever I execute `sudo vmware`, I receive a popup asking me to choose the version of `gcc`. However, unlike other errors similar to this, I am faced to choose a `gcc` version(null). Can you please help me out?

Tried but failed:

■ I tried mentioning the path as,

```
• /usr/bin/gcc 
• /usr/bin/gcc-9
• /usr/bin/gcc-10
```

■ tried updating linux-headers

Note: I currently have `gcc` version 10 and 9 installed.

[Here is the popup message showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN5MY.jpg)

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  (If using a LTS release, the software stack in use may also help, ie. GA or HWE kernel)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/Can-t-find-gcc-version-to-compile-linux-kernel-modules/m-p/2291605/highlight/true#M28807

> I had the same issue not so long ago, so, after checking online I understood I needed to compile some libraries, so, I used a repo from github for that purpose:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
>
> cd vmware-host-modules
>
> git checkout player-16.0.0
> ```
>
> After this you have to compile it, install it and either restart or
> start vmware:
>
> ```
> make
>
> sudo make install
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/vmware start
> ```
>
> If it is the first time, you should see:
>
> [image: VMware Player welcome screen]

(tested on Pop!_OS 20.10 with VMware Player version 16)